# How to hide a tablix row, tablix inside a tablix, based on (CountRows() = 0) of nested tablix

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I have 6 tablix on a report. They all use the same embedded dataset.
I am trying to get rid of the white space that occurs in my report when hiding tablix based (`CountRows() = 0`). Though I am hiding each of the six tablix based (`CountRows() = 0`) inside the row properties, I am still seeing white space all over the place.

I found on Stack Overflow that I need to nest my 6 tablix inside of another tablix (that has no data set), in their own prospective rows. I need to hide their prospective row's base on the (`CountRows() = 0`) being returned in each of the 6 tablix.

I created my empty dataset tablix and called it "`TablixContainer`"
This tablix has 6 rows.

- Row one of "`TablixContainer`" contains my nested
  "`TabixMiscAllowance`" tablix with dataset "`BalanceSheet`"
- Row two of "`TablixContainer`" contains my nested "`TabixExpenses`"
  tablix with dataset "`BalanceSheet`"
- Row three of "`TablixContainer`" contains my nested
  "`TabixTransportation`" tablix with dataset "`BalanceSheet`"

... You get the concept.

- In the visibility property, of Row one of "`TablixContainer`" to
  write an expression based on "`TabixMiscAllowance`" tablix (with
  dataset "`BalanceSheet`") returning (`CountRows() = 0`)
- In the visibility property, of Row two of "`TablixContainer`" to
  write an expression based on "`TabixExpenses`" tablix (with dataset
  "`BalanceSheet`") returning (`CountRows() = 0`)
- In the visibility property, of Row three of "`TablixContainer`" to
  write an expression based on "`TabixTransportation`" tablix (with
  dataset "`BalanceSheet`") returning (`CountRows() = 0`)

and so on... through to row 6.

I don't even know if this will get rid of the white spaces but I'd like to try it. BTW... Rectangles do NOT work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was easy to do using one tablix and nesting the individual tablix inside of each row. Just needed to make sure the grouping was set before nesting the tablix(s) inside the rows. 
P